# JQuery Cycle--Difficulty with Image Pagers

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to implement image based pagers for the plugin.
I have it working on a couple of sites like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slideshow').after('<div id="slide-nav" class="slide-nav">').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  '750',
    timeout: 4000,
    sync: 'true',
    pager:  '#slide-nav',
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
   var img = $(slide).children('.thumb').children().eq(0).attr("src");
   return '<li><a href="#"><img src="/images  /trans.png" width="20" height="20" /></a></li>';
    }
  });
```

});

On another site (utlizing CMSMS) The above code will not work unless I remove the pagerAnchorBuilder and insert:

```
        before: function() { if (window.console) console.log(this.src); }
});
```

In doing so, I can add the buttons but I can't move the a href with text-indent without also moving the background images. I'm a complete javascript newbie so this is beyond my skills. How do I preserve the pager building function while including the console.log function?